# Get ansible-playbook run information

Tags: jenkins, command-line, return, ansible

An ansible-playbook run returns 0 if everything was ok or even if some tasks changed something.

I am searching for a way to get the information in the commandline if something changed during the last run.

Does someone know a way for this?

The background is that I want to monitor my servers via an Jenkins pipeline an get an alarm if something changed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json` as Ansible stdout callback plugin, this way Ansible will return machine parsable output in JSON format.

For example:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml | jq '.stats | map(select(.changed > 0)) | length'
```

will print out number of hosts that have something changed.

Comment: Nice solution for a basic command line run. Unfortantly it will break my Jenkins (output) log. Can't do this to the team but thanks a lot

Comment: Ok. You can always run Ansible with file logging turned on and `grep` it after playbook execution to find if there is some `changed=XX` lines present.

Comment: nice. What if you want more than one callback plugin? Are they comma separated?