# Write to file specified by user from command line argument - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a line to a file using `lineinfile`.

The name of the file is to be passed to the playbook at run time by the user as a command line argument.

Here is what the task looks like:

```
  # Check for timezone.
    - name: check timezone
      tags: timezoneCheck
      register: timezoneCheckOut
      shell: timedatectl | grep -i "Time Zone" | awk --field-separator=":" '{print $2}' | awk --field-separator=" " '{print $1}'
    - lineinfile:
        path: {{ output }}
        line: "Did not find { DesiredTimeZone }"
        create: True
        state: present
        insertafter: EOF
      when: timezoneCheckOut.stdout != DesiredTimezone
    - debug: var=timezoneCheckOut.stdout
```

My questions are:
1. How do I specify the command line argument to be the destination file to write to (`path`)?
2. How do I append the argument `DesiredTimeZone` (specified in an external variables file) to the `line` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My following answer might not be your solutions.

1. how to specify the command argument for output variable.

`ansible-playbook yourplaybook.yml -e output=/path/to/outputfile`

2. how to include DesiredTimeZone variable from external file.

`vars_files:
    - external.yml`

### full playbook.yml for testing on local:

- yourplaybook.yml

`- name: For testing
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - external.yml`

`tasks:
    - name: check timezone
      tags: timezoneCheck
      register: timezoneCheckOut
      shell: timedatectl | grep -i "Time Zone" | awk -F":" '{print $2}' |  awk --field-separator=" " '{print $1}'`

`- debug: var=timezoneCheckOut.stdout`

`- lineinfile:
        path: "{{ output }}"
        line: "Did not find {{ DesiredTimeZone }}"
        create: True
        state: present
        insertafter: EOF
      when: timezoneCheckOut.stdout != DesiredTimeZone`

- external.yml (place the same level with yourplaybook.yml)

`---
DesiredTimeZone: "Asia/Tokyo"`

Answer (score 2):

With Ansible you should *define the desired state*. Period.

The correct way of doing this is to just use [timezone](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/timezone_module.html) module:

```
- name: set timezone
  timezone:
    name: "{{ DesiredTimeZone }}"
```

No need to jump through the hoops with shell, register, compare, print...

If you want to put system into the desired state, just run playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -e DesiredTimeZone=Asia/Tokyo timezone_playbook.yml
```

Ansible will ensure that all hosts in question will have the `DesiredTimeZone`.

If you just want to *check if you system comply to desired state*, use `--check` switch:

```
ansible-playbook -e DesiredTimeZone=Asia/Tokyo --check timezone_playbook.yml
```

In this case Ansible will just print to the log what should be changed in the current state to become desired state and don't make any actual changes.

Comment: Agreed. I am attempting to write a sort of audit script to ensure all our servers are aligned properly. We create and destroy a number of servers and need to ensure everything is the same.

Comment: Pay close attention to `--check` option. Also you can force Ansible to spit out JSON as its output for easy machine analysis (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44717744/2795592) answer)